# nHibernate set referenced property by id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have the following method which is called from Ajax:

```
 [Authorize]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public JsonNetResult CreateOrUpdateTimeRecord(TimeRecord tr)
    {

        TimeRecord trLocal;
        if (tr.Id == -1 || tr.Id == 0)
        {
            trLocal = new TimeRecord
            {
                Description = tr.Description,
                StartTime = tr.StartTime,
                EndTime = tr.EndTime,
                User =new myTimeMvc.Models.NHibernate.Models.User {Id = tr.User.Id},// _userRepo.Get(tr.User.Id),
                Hdt = new Hdt {Id = tr.Hdt.Id}//_hdtRepo.Get(tr.Hdt.Id)
            };

            _timeRepo.Insert(trLocal);

        }
        else
        {
            trLocal = _timeRepo.Get(tr.Id);

            trLocal.Description = tr.Description;
            trLocal.StartTime = tr.StartTime;
            trLocal.EndTime = tr.EndTime;

            _timeRepo.Update(trLocal);
        }

        ...
    }
```

As you can see my TimeRecord has a reference to User and Hdt. Now I started to work with NHibernate Profiler which complains when I resolve my properties by loading them from their coresponding repositories. Which is clear to me since I actually don't need to query the database for that since I have the ID's for this objects.

```
 User = _userRepo.Get(tr.User.Id),
 Hdt = _hdtRepo.Get(tr.Hdt.Id)
```

But I'm not 100% sure if I can use this instead:

```
User =new myTimeMvc.Models.NHibernate.Models.User {Id = tr.User.Id},,
Hdt = new Hdt {Id = tr.Hdt.Id}
```

I guess NHibernate lazy proxies work the same way since they only contain just the ID of the related object and load the rest when it is needed. Do I have to attach this "new" oject anyway to my session?
Can someone tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways how to achieve that. One of them could be using the **`Load()`** method. Check Ayendes post: [NHibernate – The difference between Get, Load and querying by id](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id), an extract:

> Load will never return null. It will always return an entity or throw an exception. Because that is the contract that we have we it, **it is permissible for Load to not hit the database when you call it, it is free to return a proxy instead**.

Other words, we can do something like this

```
User = _userRepo.Load(tr.User.Id),
Hdt = _hdtRepo.Load(tr.Hdt.Id)
```

Where the `Load` would be encapsulating the `session.Load()`